# RCA QU26 Speakers connection question

Tags: speakers

I'm restoring an old RCA radio from the 1940's.
From looking the schematic I have this question: What is the theory behind this speakers connection arrangement? What's the benefit of using an electrodynamic speaker with a permanent magnet speaker?
[image]

Comment: Before inexpensive  strong AlNiCo magnets were possible, they used electro-magnets , here with the option for either.

Comment: As the PM speaker plugs in, perhaps it's an optional extra to provide sound in another room. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423864/em-vs-pm-speaker/423881#423881 for more about the wound-field speaker. (note the NEUT. COIL on the field armature : it cancels out hum induced by ripple in the field winding/PSU choke

Comment: The Speaker electromagnet was used as a filter choke in many radio power supplies. That way they got a two for one. The major benefit is it is easier to mount a speaker rather then a cumbersome chjoke. The electrodynamic speaker in that time frame sounded better especially at the lower frequencies.